# How to apply a filter in a entity mapping C# / Entity Framework / Fluent?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, mapping, dbcontext, ef-fluent-api

i have maintened a big web system built some years ago and it is already in production (i am saying this to to emphasize the complexity of tinkering with the system structure).

Till now this system has been working with physical exclusion of database records, however now there is a necessity to change it to logical exclusion (updating the status (to "D") of a register in table).

My entities are mapped by FluentApi.
My properties in context are built using DbSet, example:
DbSet Person {get;set;}

I would like to know a way to only fetch records in my entity with status != "D" straight from entity mapping or through an overall filter that always executes when i call my  entity in context.

I have tried a solution like suggested here:

http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/using-a-filtereddbset-with-entity-framework-to-have-dynamic-filtering

It actually it works fine to fetch the data i want however, i cannot use the methods to change the record like "AddOrUpdate" because when i use that solution my property needs to be a **IDbSet** and not a **DbSet**.

Example:
To use the solution suggested in the above link the property must be changed from this:

**DbSet Person { get; set; }**

to this:

**IDbSet Person { get; set; }**

Sample code:

```
// My Entity
public class Person
{
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Status {get; set;}
        public ICollection<Address> PersonAddress {get; set;}
}

// My Context example
public class MyContext : DbContext
{  
    public MyContext(System.Data.Common.DbConnection conn, bool contextOwnsConnection) : base(conn, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        ConnectionString = conn.ConnectionString;
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        SetDatabaseSettings(); //NLS and regional configurations

        //Here i am calling the method built in the link above
        this.Person = new FilteredDbSet<Person>(this, a => !a.Status.Equals("D"));
    } 

    // This is now a IDbSet type
    public IDbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    // The others are DbSet type
    public DbSet<Address> Adressess { get; set; }
}

// Any use of context
public class PersonsClass{

    private readonly MyContext context;

    public PersonsClass(MyContext context)
    {
        this.contexto = context;
    }

    // Considering the filter applied in MyContext constructor method 
    // this method returns all "person" with status property != D (OK)
    public List<Person> ListAllPersons()
    {
        return context.Person.toList();         
    }

    // When try to perform add or update method, the system throws the following exception:
    // "Unable to call public, instance method AddOrUpdate on derived IDbSet type 'Context.FilteredDbSet`1[Entities.Person]'. Method not found."
    // I believe that this is happening because "AddOrUpdate" method belongs to DbSet class instead of IDbSet interface.
    public void UpdatePerson(Person newPerson)
    {
        context.Person.AddOrUpdate(newPerson);
    }
}
```

So, when i try to change a record of this entity the exception: "Unable to call public, instance method AddOrUpdate on derived IDbSet type 'Context.FilteredDbSet`1[Entities.Person]'. Method not found." is thrown.

Any tips about how to go through it?

Comment: Does up casting throw any exceptions? Also, can you share your code or some snippets?

Comment: Hi mohammedlok. I added the requested information in main post. Thanks

Comment: The method `AddOrUpdate` is equivalent to an `UPSERT` operation from database terminology and is useful when **seeding** data. It has a lot of overheads and should not be used in your case. Find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176991(v=vs.113).aspx) more. Have you tried using the `Add(TEntity)` method as listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233(v=vs.113).aspx)?

Comment: Another way to do this would be to implement a repository pattern into your service and then filter with LINQ over `PersonRepositry`. However, ideally, that doesn't seem correct as well. Afterall, filtering is business logic that should be done in the service layer.

Comment: Hi mohammedlok, the method Add(TEntity) only adds a new record in database.

I need to add if there is no a record with specific PK, or update it if there is already a record with specific PK.

Comment: Are you calling `SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: Yes, but the exception have been thrown before it.
I follow your advice to avoid use AddOrUpdate and now i can be able to handle it.
Add method when it is a new register and when it is an update i just change the entity state to "System.Data.EntityState.Modified" and then call SaveChanges();
It worked till now... i will proceed with some tests and if it works fine, that is the solution!! =)